# SwiftUI: Scrollview with both axes enabled produces layout mess

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, scrollview

### The Problem

In our brand new SwiftUI project (Multiplatform app for iPhone, iPad and Mac) we are using a `ScrollView` with both `.horizontal` and `.vertical` axes enabled. In the end it all looks like a spreadsheet.

Inside of `ScrollView` we are using `LazyVStack` with `pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders, .sectionFooters]`. All `Footer`, `Header` and the content cells are wrapped into a `LazyHStack` each. The lazy stacks are needed due to performance reasones when rows and columns are growing.

And this exactly seems to be the problem. `ScrollView` produces a real layout mess when scrolling in both axes at the same time.

### Tested Remedies

I tried several workarounds with no success.
We built our own lazy loading horizontal stack view which shows only the cells whose indexes are in the visible frame of the scrollview, and which sets dynamic calculated leading and trailing padding.

I tried the [Introspect for SwiftUI](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) packacke to set `usesPredominantAxisScrolling` for macOS and `isDirectionalLockEnabled` for iOS. None of this works as expected.

I also tried a workaround to manually lock one axis when the other one is scrolling. This works fine on iOS but it doesn't on macOS due to extreme poor performance (I think it's caused by the missing `NSScrollViewDelegate` and scroll events are being propagated via `NotificationCenter`).

### How does it look?

To give you a better idea of what I mean, I have screenshots for both iOS and macOS.

[image: SwiftUI ScrollView on iOS]

[image: SwiftUI ScrollView on macOS]

Here you can watch short screen recording for both [iOS](https://youtu.be/9s2soFggi88) and [macOS](https://youtu.be/94f8AOCBsEY).

### Example Code

And this is the sample code used for the screenshots. So you can just create a new `Multiplatform` project and paste the code below in the `ContentView.swift` file. That's all.

```swift
import SwiftUI

let numberOfColums: Int = 150
let numberOfRows: Int = 350

struct ContentView: View {
    var items: [[Item]] = {
        var items: [[Item]] = [[]]
        for rowIndex in 0..<numberOfRows {
            var row: [Item] = []
            for columnIndex in 0..<numberOfColums {
                row.append(Item(column: columnIndex, row: rowIndex))
            }
            items.append(row)
        }
        return items
    }()

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders, .sectionFooters]) {
                    Section(header: Header()) {
                        ForEach(0..<items.count, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
                            let row = items[rowIndex]
                            LazyHStack(spacing: 1) {
                                ForEach(0..<row.count, id: \.self) { columnIndex in
                                    Text("\(columnIndex):\(rowIndex)")
                                        .frame(width: 100)
                                        .padding()
                                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top])
        }
        .padding(.top, 1)
    }
}

struct Header: View {
    var body: some View {
        LazyHStack(spacing: 1) {
            ForEach(0..<numberOfColums, id: \.self) { idx in
                Text("Col \(idx)")
                    .frame(width: 100)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct Item: Hashable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var column: Int
    var row: Int
}
```

### Can You Help?

Okay, long story short...
Does anybody know a real working solution for this issue?
Is it a known SwiftUI `ScrollView` bug?

If there were a way to lock one scrolling direction while the other one is being scrolled, then I could deal with that. But at the moment, unfortunately, it is not usable for us.

So any solution is highly appreciated!

Comment: I have seen this issue related to `LazyVStack`. Try to replace it with its nonlazy version.

Comment: I seems answered on such question... in such layout only one axis should be lazy (which one is going to be shorter)... try to use instead LazyVStack + HStack

Comment: @Asperi I tried that and it works on both iOS and macOS. On iOS it works very well, but on macOS vertical scroll performance is *very* poor aka unacceptable!

Comment: Yes there were other questions around this issue. Seems to be a bug. No workaround in the moment as far as I know.

Comment: I gave it a couple of hours, fixed with only limited number of columns (around 15).
1- remove the section header.
2- use HStack instead of LazyHStack.
3- as for the header I created a separate scrollview on top with synced offset to the main scrollview, [check this for synced scrollviews.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70846238/654114)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you don't want to use a Grid for this layout?

Here is the article I would suggest you read to solve this problem:
https://swiftui-lab.com/impossible-grids/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will have a look at it.

The data of our project are row based. Each row is one "record". Number of columns can vary over all rows, and the width of each column is flexible (user editable). I'm not quite sure if this is possible with a grid layout.